# What is the Girsanov density as a functional on the canonical path space $C[0,1]$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

I'll formulate the question via an example.

On $( C[0,1], \mathcal{C} )$, where $C[0,1]$ is the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{C}$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra given by uniform topology, consider Wiener measure $\mathbb{P}$. Denote by $t \mapsto W_t$ the Brownian paths given by $\mathbb{P}$.

Let $X$ be specified via 
$$
dX = \mu(X) dt + dW,
$$ 
where $\mu: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is fixed.

Girsanov's theorem says, under the measure $\mathbb{Q}$ given by (assume, e.g., Novikov's condition holds)
$$
\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} } = e^{ \int_0^1 \mu(X) dW - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \mu(X)^2 dt },
$$
the $\mathbb{Q}$-law of $W$ is the $\mathbb{P}$-law of $X$.

**Question**

The Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} }$ is specified via stochastic integral. But in principle, a Radon-Nikodym derivative is an object one must be able to define $\omega$-by-$\omega$, $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely in this case. So what is $\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} }$ as a functional on $C[0,1]$ (strictly speaking on the support of $\mathbb{P}$)?

**Conjecture**

Ignore that Brownian paths do not have finite variation, etc.
Formally, it is the functional $\phi : C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(\cdot) \stackrel{\phi}{\mapsto} e^{\int_0^1 \mu(x(t)) df(t) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \mu^2(x(t)) dt }
$$
where $dx = \mu(x) dt + df$, and $\int_0^1 \mu(x(t)) df(t)$ is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral with respect to $df$. In other words, given $f \in C[0,1]$, one acts as if $f$ is a realization of Brownian path and substitute formally into the expression for $\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} }$. Is this correct in some sense---e.g. discretize into step functions and taking weak limit in the Skorohod space $D[0,1]$...?

**Suggestive Example**

Suppose $dX = a \, dt + dW$ where $a$ is a real number.
Then, $\omega$-by-$\omega$, the Radon-Nikodym derivative
$$
\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} } = e^{ \int_0^1 a dW - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 a^2 dt },
$$
is given by the functional
$$
f(\cdot) \stackrel{\phi}{\mapsto} e^{ a \int_0^1  df(t) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 a^2 dt }
$$
where $\int_0^1  df(t)$ is interpreted as $f(1) - f(0)$.

Comment: I don't understand your question: $\exp(\int_0^1 \mu(X_s)\,d W_s - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \mu(X_s)^2 \,d s )$ is a measurable function on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ (or $(C[0,1], \mathcal{C})$). Why is this not enough for considering it as $\frac{\,d \mathbb{Q}}{\, d \mathbb{P}}$?

Comment: It certainly defines $\frac{\,d \mathbb{Q}}{\, d \mathbb{P}}$ as a measurable function on  $(C[0,1], \mathcal{C})$. Whether it's enough depends on what one needs. In principle, for any measurable function $\phi$ defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$, if I give you an $\omega \in \Omega$, you should be able to tell me what $\phi(\omega)$ is, without reference to any probability measure. So, in this case, you say you have a (measurable) function/functional $\phi$ on $(C[0,1], \mathcal{C})$, so if I give you $f\in C[0,1]$ (that's in the support of the Wiener measure), what is $\phi(f)$?

Comment: A natural question is, e.g. what is the law of $\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} }$ under some other measure $\mathbb{Q}'$? In this case, one needs to know $\frac{d \mathbb{Q} }{ d\mathbb{P} }$ more explicitly.

Comment: Crossposted to MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337990/girsanov-density-as-a-functional-on-c0-1

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thank you.